# How to make class member process safe in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am doing some tasks on a class which spawns multiple processes over an iterator to makesure each entry be processed once. The code is Like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

Class MyClass():
    def __init__():
        self.index=[blabla]
        self.iterator=0
        self.workers=[mp.Process(target=self.worker, args=(self.lock, args) for i in range(10)]
    def worker(self, lock, args):
        # I intend to use lock to make only one subprocs read index 
        # list until iterator goes to next 
        while some_condition:
            lock.acquire()
            now_item=self.index[self.iterator]
            self._next_iter()
            lock.release()
            ...# do something on now_item
    def._next_iter(self):
        #do some checks and +1 on iterator
```

But it seems that all subprocess starts at iterator=0 and doing their own loops.
I know it is possible to synchronize them with a `Queue()` object, but what if we don't use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processes do not share memory between themselves. Therefore, changes applied to a variable within a process will not be propagated to siblings.

To share variables across processes in Python you can take a look at the primitives offered by the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) module. In your particular case, a [shared value](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) should be enough.